while using cartographer, map frame is not found
Problem,
am spawning multiple turtlebots(Turtlebot3) in ros2 env, and each have topics as follows,
Ros2 topics
/clock
/parameter_events
/performance_metrics
/robot1/cmd_vel
/robot1/imu
/robot1/joint_states
/robot1/odom
/robot1/robot_description
/robot1/scan
/robot2/cmd_vel
/robot2/imu
/robot2/joint_states
/robot2/odom
/robot2/robot_description
/robot2/scan
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
The problem is, when the topics have namespace "robot1" or "robot2", thee cartographer is not publishing a map or initiating a map frame,
whereas when there are no name spaces, it works fine, is there any way i could handle the namespace and at the same time gain individual maps from the bots and get unique map topics and map frames?
THanking you
